# Provide a fallback column to join to if no match is found in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, join, hiveql

I have a transaction table with a product name, a couple of other attributes and a count.

I'm currently joining this table to a reference table on product name and returning some additional product attributes.  However in most cases product name in the transaction table does not match the entry in the reference table.

So i maintain a list of variations on product name with a variant and a target column, join my table to this variation table first and then use the target to join to the Product Reference.

The issue i'm having is, sometimes the data does not work going through the variations table and could join directly to the reference table (in this situation we may have in the transactional table a product name which meets the 'target' name but not the variant.

I know this could be fixed by updating the variants table, but for the sake of speed, i've been trying to find a way to join to the variation table on the variation column, and then if a record does not match try to join to the 'target' column.

Is this possible in SQL?

Essentially try to join Column X to Column A, if not found try join against Column B.

I've got something like the below which works.

```
    SELECT
    transaction_data.product AS product_name,
    transaction_data.count AS sales,
    transaction_data.date as sale_date,
    transaction_data.region AS region_code,
    product_table_master.product_official_name,
    product_table_master.product_type
FROM
    transaction_data
JOIN
    product_variations AS product_name_variant 
        ON transaction_data.product_name = product_name_variant.variation
JOIN
    product_table AS product_table_master
        ON product_name_variant.target =  product_table_master.product_official_name
```

But havent found a way of doing this with any of my experiments (adding an additional join on Target).

```
/* JOIN
    product_variations AS product_name_variant2 
        ON transaction_data.product_name = product_name_variant.target



product_variations 
variant   | target
Computer  | Computer
PC        | Computer
Laptop    | Computer
Hat       | Headwear
Cap       | Headwear


transaction_data
product   | sales
Computer  | 4
PC        | 3
Laptop    | 6
Headwear  | 3
Cap       | 1
```

In the Sample above, first the transaction data is joined to variant in the product_variations table.  In this case Computer, PC and Laptop, all map to the target Computer, which is used in the next join to the master reference table.

However, the problem i have is Headwear in the transaction data doesnt appear in the product variations table as a variant, so joining will not work.  Unless i can join to the Target column.

Comment: I am just really confused.  What is `product_variations2`?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Added some sample data

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you to perform a left outer join on X and A.
2. get the matched results.
3. Join non-matched elements with B.
4. Merge the result 2 & 3 to get the final reference table.